# Converting 2 column data file to row format

Tags: awk, sed

i am Beginner Unix user,trying to convert a file having 2 columns to a row format data file.

Sample data file : HEADER Count: 6 , EMPID, EMPNAME,SALARY,DEPT,AGE,JOD

```
col1;col2

empid;1001
empname;ABC
salary;3000
dept;ABC
age;24
JOD;20170101
empid;2001
salary;5000
dept;XYZ
age;27
JOD;20170303
empid;1002
empname;MAN
salary;11000
dept;SCI
age;30
JOD;20180607
empid;1005
empname;NAME
salary;10200
dept;XYZ
JOD;20161212
```

Below is the code i have tried, but i am not getting desired output.

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=';'
       OFS=';'
       RS="\n"
Print An = "empid", Bn = "empname", Cn = "salary", Dn = "Dept", En = "age", Fn = "DOJ"
     }
     {
     A=B=C=D=E=F=" "
     for ( i = 1; i<=NF; i++)
          {
           if($i == An)
                A = $(i+1)
           if($i == Bn)
                B = $(i+1)
           if($i == Cn)
                C = $(i+1)
           if($i == Dn)
                D = $(i+1)
           if($i == En)
                E = $(i+1)
           if($i == Fn)
                F = $(i+1)
             }
            print A, B, C, D, E, F
             }' FILE.txt >New_file.txt
```

let me know if anything is required from my side. 
i am using PUTTY for unix, 64 bit intel core i5-5300U CPU, 2.30GHz.

Could  you please help me out with this.I would be very helpful.

Regards,
Naresh

Comment: you're missing empname for the second dataset and age for the last dataset, is this a mistake ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input. If `col1;col2` followed by a blank line isn't REALLY present in your real data then please remove it from the example you provided.

Comment: Hi Plumo, It's not a mistake file is missing with certain data between these 6 set of values. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have a consistent number of fields in each input record, a 2-pass approach is required to avoid having to hard-code column names in your code:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR {
    if ( !($1 in colNrs) ) {
        colNrs[$1] = ++numCols
        hdr = (numCols>1 ? hdr OFS : "") $1
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 { print hdr }
{ colNr = colNrs[$1] }
colNr in vals { prt() }
{ vals[colNr] = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   colNr) {
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", vals[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete vals
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
empid;empname;salary;dept;age;JOD
1001;ABC;3000;ABC;24;20170101
2001;;5000;XYZ;27;20170303
1002;MAN;11000;SCI;30;20180607
1005;NAME;10200;XYZ;;20161212
```

To use the above awk script in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/env bash

... other shell stuff ...

awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR {
    if ( !($1 in colNrs) ) {
        colNrs[$1] = ++numCols
        hdr = (numCols>1 ? hdr OFS : "") $1
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 { print hdr }
{ colNr = colNrs[$1] }
colNr in vals { prt() }
{ vals[colNr] = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   colNr) {
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", vals[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete vals
}
' file file

... other shell stuff ...
```

Comment: Hi Ed Morton, Thanks for the solution you have provided. If may i ask could you please Explain it. Regards, Naresh

Comment: HI Ed, I have tested your solution. I am getting nothing but 5 semicolons in target file i.e =  ;;;;; .

Comment: My best guess is that you ran `awk -f tst.awk file` instead of `awk -f tst.awk file file`. As I said, it's a 2 pass solution so it needs to read `file` twice.

Comment: Hi Ed, The solution is working fine, Could you please explain me what and how its working. If i can include it in my script or not. because when i try to include whole code in script its saying me : FOR READING ( FILE NAME TOO LONG) for two pass approach. Regards, Naresh

Comment: When you say `can include it in my script` I'm assuming you mean include it in a shell script so I updated my answer to explicitly show how to do that. The NR==FNR block is being executed for the first pass of the file and just creating a list of the column names as it finds them. The FNR==1 block is hit for the first lin of the 2nd pass of the file and just prints the header string built up during that first pass. The rest populates an array of values for each column number and when it hits a column number it already say that means it went 1 past the end of the record and prints the array.

Comment: Hi Ed, Thank you for your valuable time and your expertise to resolve the issue i was facing. The solution is working fine with awk script. I will try to include in my script as you have mentioned explicitly. Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are syntax errors in your code.

The single quotes in your `BEGIN`block should be double

```
BEGIN {FS=";";
       OFS=";";
       RS="\n";
```

Secondly, you cannot assign variables and print in the way that you have done and this needs correction.

Thirdly Dn = "Date" and the field in your records is "date" and you have the same issue with "DOJ"/"JOD"

```
        An = "empid"; Bn = "empname"; Cn = "salary"; Dn = "dept"; En = "age"; Fn = "JOD";
        print An, Bn, Cn, Dn, En, Fn
     }
```

These corrections to the `BEGIN` block get you to ...

```
empid;empname;salary;dept;age;JOD
1001; ; ; ; ; 
 ;ABC; ; ; ; 
 ; ;3000; ; ; 
 ; ; ;ABC; ; 
 ; ; ; ;24; 
 ; ; ; ; ;20170101
2001; ; ; ; ; 
 ; ;5000; ; ; 
 ; ; ;XYZ; ; 
 ; ; ; ;27; 
 ; ; ; ; ;20170303
1002; ; ; ; ; 
 ;MAN; ; ; ; 
 ; ;11000; ; ; 
 ; ; ;SCI; ; 
 ; ; ; ;30; 
 ; ; ; ; ;20180607
1005; ; ; ; ; 
 ;NAME; ; ; ; 
 ; ;10200; ; ; 
 ; ; ;XYZ; ; 
 ; ; ; ; ;20161212
```

Which is because of logic errors.

As @pLumo points out there are missing data fields in your data sets and your code does not allow for this, but more, `awk` is printing at every record (every line) and not every record set (just before the occurrence of `empid`).

There are many ways to skin this particular cat but since I am in a good mood today here's a simple one to follow for a beginner to learn arrays....

In the `BEGIN` block load an array with the field numbers you want using the field names as the indices and print the titles

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN{
    fields["empid"]=1;
    fields["empname"]=2;
    fields["salary"]=3;
    fields["dept"]=4;
    fields["age"]=5;
    fields["JOD"]=6;
    print "empid;empname;salary;dept;age;JOD"
    }
```

if the first field is "empid" and `&&` it is not the first record `NR>1` then iterate over the array that will contain your field values (the array is empty when `NR==1` this is why we skip it) and after you have printed the array then empty it for reuse by `delete`

```
    $1=="empid" && NR>1 {
         for (f=1; f<6; f++) printf field[f]";"; print field[6]; delete field}
```

For every line in the file, load the value `$2` into your array of values `field` using the field number recovered from the `fields` array we built in the `BEGIN` block as an index, based upon the field name in `$1`

```
   {field[fields[$1]]=$2
```

The array will still be loaded with unprinted values when you get to the end of the file and so you have to print the array one last time

```
    }END{for (f=1; f<6; f++) printf field[f]";"; print field[6]}' file1
```

**Edit**

With this script copy/pasted into the terminal

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN{
    fields["empid"]=1;
    fields["empname"]=2;
    fields["salary"]=3;
    fields["dept"]=4;
    fields["age"]=5;
    fields["JOD"]=6;
    print "empid;empname;salary;dept;age;JOD"
    }$1=="empid" && NR>1 {
         for (f=1; f<6; f++) printf field[f]";"; print field[6]; delete field}{field[fields[$1]]=$2 
         }END{for (f=1; f<6; f++) printf field[f]";"; print field[6]}' file1
```

With this input

```
empid;1001
empname;ABC
salary;3000
dept;ABC
age;24
JOD;20170101
empid;2001
salary;5000
dept;XYZ
age;27
JOD;20170303
empid;1002
empname;MAN
salary;11000
dept;SCI
age;30
JOD;20180607
empid;1005
empname;NAME
salary;10200
dept;XYZ
JOD;20161212
```

Output is

```
empid;empname;salary;dept;age;JOD
1001;ABC;3000;ABC;24;20170101
2001;;5000;XYZ;27;20170303
1002;MAN;11000;SCI;30;20180607
1005;NAME;10200;XYZ;;20161212
```

Comment: Hi Bu5hman, Thanks for pointing out the errors, it seems those are typo errors. I will try out the solution you have proposed and let you know the result. Regards, Naresh

Comment: Hi Bu5hMan, Could you please confirm if i have to replace your solution with mine or I have to add you solution to my code. Regards,Naresh

Comment: My code should work standalone but for practice you could amend your own code....

Comment: i have tried both ways.. amending with my code and standalone your solution.. but still a blank file and semicolons at last row.

Comment: So there are few changes i have made in your code 1st: field should be replaced with fields while printing in for statement.  2nd: Delete fields moved to last for statement as it was printing only first set of values in row format and rest semicolon for other set of values

Comment: empid;empname;salary;dept;age;JOD
1001;ABC;3000;ABC;24;20170101
2001;**ABC**;5000;XYZ;27;20170303
1002;MAN;11000;SCI;30;20180607
1005;NAME;10200;XYZ;**30**;20161212

Comment: After above changes i am getting above output where missing values is replaced with previous record value, which should be NULL.